# ¿como manejar las variables de sesión de php para evitar el login de un mismo usuario en diferentes equipos?

Tags: php, php7

Pasa que estoy utilizando variables de SESSION para el login en una pagina, la intención es que un usuario solo pueda iniciar sesión una vez, y que si intenta iniciar sesión otra vez, con el mismo usuario y con la primera sesión ya abierta, no lo permita... Esto me funciona bien cuando hago pruebas en el mismo PC, pero si ingreso a la pagina desde otro PC e inicio sesión con el mismo usuario que ya tiene sesión abierta desde el otro PC, me permite ingresar nuevamente como si fuera una nueva sesión...

Explicado lo anterior, mis dudas son:

1. ¿Las variables de session solo funcionan en el mismo pc?
2. ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer que las variables de session funcionen para varios equipos?
3. ¿Tendría que hacerlo por medio de consultas en bd para lograr lo que quiero?

En conclusión, ¿como podría manejar las variables de sesión de php para evitar el login de un mismo usuario en diferentes equipos?

Comment: Andres, trata de acomodar tu pregunta, coloca al final algo como En conclusión, ¿como podría manejar las variables de sesión de php para evitar el login de un mismo usuario en diferentes equipos? y también le agregas ese titulo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) ¿Las variables de sesión solo funcionan en el mismo pc?**

Las variables de sesión en php se comparten para la aplicación que esta corriendo o mejor dicho el script, esta debe validarse, ya que podria darte un error de que la sessión ya se ha iniciado.

La sesión que creas para tu usuario se mantiene para todo el navegador ( y cada uno de ellos tendra una distinta si los conectas).

Para las pestañas abiertas solo debes comprobarlas adecuadamente, agrego aquí un ejemplo pequeño:

*Crear sesión:*

```
<?php
    // validas tu login y demas cosas
    $session = array(
        "nivel_de_acceso" => $nivel_de_acceso,
        "connected" =>True,
        "id_usuario" => $id_usuario,
    );
    $_SESSION["logged"] = $session;

?>
```

**Luego para verificarla en cada php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["logged"]) and $_SESSION["logged"]["connected"] == True){
        // haces tu redireccion, aqui empleo mvc, pero puedes pasar la ruta directa
        header("location: index.php?action=main");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Aqui tambien puedes agregar un script de javascript para evitar abrir mas de una pestaña, estilo un banco. Yo aplique esta a un sistema y me funciono:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661543/how-to-know-if-browser-tab-is-already-open-using-javascript

Aquí pasan por lo general 2 problemas:

- No validan el login y por tanto puedes loguearte varias veces, pendiente con ello
- Validan solo en el login, las demás paginas serán accesibles para cualquiera
- En un equipo de la misma red u otro navegador podrías conectarte de nuevo aunque las dos primeras funcionen bien, solución ve al punto 3.

**2) ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer que las variables de session funcionen para varios equipos?**

¿Que fin tendría esto?, según el podría darte opciones, lo que podrías hacer es tener tablas donde se guarden los usuarios según ID, verificando digamos con unos datos ya preestablecidos que usuarios mantienen sesiones similares

**3) ¿Tendría que hacerlo por medio de consultas en bd para lograr lo que quiero?**

Exactamente, una vez validez la sesión debes buscar al usuario (en mi caso) y colocar un valor true o 1 en el campo conectado, de modo que si tratan de acceder desde otra pc o desde otro navegador este verifique en la bd.

Ahora bien, no solo basta verificar que sea cuando se conecte, sino que al hacer logout también regrese el valor a 0, y cuando la sesión expire, tanto con el navegador abierto o cerrado. ¿como se hace?

Para esto ultimo puedes verificar la actividad del usuario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713863/php-mysql-update-database-on-session-timeout o de una forma mas simple, agregar un codigo javascript para que al cerrar la pestaña te haga un llamado ajax y te cambie la sesión a 0 :)

**4) Problemática de estas soluciones**

Ahora bien, digamos trabajas en una empresa y tu sistema es accesible desde cualquier lugar, tu estas en tu oficina (1er piso) y te llama a donde tu jefe (5to piso) en el apuro dejas abierta la sesión, y dura 1 hora para expirar.
Cuando te conectas a la aplicación para mostrarle a tu jefe el reporte xyz, te muestra que estas ya conectado, ¿como darle solución a esto? sin ir al 1er piso a cerrarla.

Sencillo, agregamos otra columna en nuestra tabla usuarios llamada IP, guardaremos el IP de nuestro equipo al conectarnos.

Entonces tu consulta haría algo como:

```
esta conectado? SI
esta en otra ip? SI
lo desconecto
conecto en esta ip
```

**BONUS**: ¿Como funcionan las sesiones en php?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535697/how-do-php-sessions-work-not-how-are-they-used

Comment: Si, me lo imaginaba, tendré q usar bd, gracias por la aclaración y por el ejemplo.

Comment: @andresuarez_95 gracias por votar positivo, trata de seguir el consejo que te di en tu pregunta

Comment: `Si, porque ellas son cookies que se crean en el navegador.` Como así ? lo único que se crea en el navegador del cliente es una (1) coockie que contiene el ID de la sesión nada mas, todo lo demás se trata del lado del servidor.

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo sobre eso, cuando coloque el cambio me la editaron, iba a escribir (hasta donde se, debo leer sobre esto) gracias por anotarlo

Comment: * cada navegador en el mismo pc tendrá su propia sesión.

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo aunque si leo lo que escribi esta bien, porque hablo de las sesiones en plural. pero es una cookie para el navegador por donde viaja la sesión